# I am not getting any result when addend a variable

Tags: r, sum, summarize, mutate

My dataset, `Despesa_2021_Red`, is the following (I just copy a small sample):

```
structure(list(grup_CNAE_Red = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 
11L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Aliments i begudes no alcohòliques", 
"Begudes alcohòliques i tabac", "Vestit i calçat", "Habitatge", 
"Mobles i parament de la llar", "Salut", "Transport", "Comunicacions", 
"Oci i cultura", "Educació", "Restaurants i hotels", "Altres béns i serveis"
), class = "factor"), despesatotal = structure(c(57629.21, 186827.47, 
210879.71, 105439.85, 91381.21, 344980.45, 117155.39, 44334.78, 
426350.53, 199874.51, 41750.52), format.stata = "%12.0g"), despesamonetaria = structure(c(57629.21, 
186827.47, 210879.71, 105439.85, 91381.21, 344980.45, 117155.39, 
44334.78, 426350.53, 199874.51, 41750.52), format.stata = "%12.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My code is such:

```
despesatotal_llar <- Despesa_2021_Red %>%
  select("grup_CNAE_Red", "despesatotal", "despesamonetaria") %>%
  group_by(grup_CNAE_Red) %>%
  mutate(despesatotal = sum(despesatotal)) %>%
  mutate(despesamonetaria=sum(despesamonetaria)) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, sum, na.rm=TRUE) %>%
  adorn_totals("row")%>% 
  mutate(proporcio_total=(despesatotal/last(despesatotal))*100)%>% 
  mutate(proporcio_monetaria=(despesamonetaria/last(despesamonetaria))*100)
```

And I am getting the following:

```
structure(list(grup_CNAE_Red = c("Aliments i begudes no alcohòliques", 
"Begudes alcohòliques i tabac", "Vestit i calçat", "Habitatge", 
"Mobles i parament de la llar", "Salut", "Transport", "Comunicacions", 
"Oci i cultura", "Educació", "Restaurants i hotels", "Altres béns i serveis"
), despesatotal = c(72550491701696000, 514691112000324, 853338207044935, 
26964294577958360, 1948071319668620, 816954427256048, 3759365484618088, 
566787384086023, 1978802503248884, 122472236797361, 1603169228759177, 
4471711267049114), despesamonetaria = c(71922177505370160, 514060934967651, 
852780110238510, 9150794396419362, 1946413539609788, 816837090808086, 
3753590662112487, 565752314409180, 1978515407744175, 120444283968143, 
0, 4440563217947374)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tabyl", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), core = structure(list(grup_CNAE_Red = structure(1:12, .Label = c("Aliments i begudes no alcohòliques", 
"Begudes alcohòliques i tabac", "Vestit i calçat", "Habitatge", 
"Mobles i parament de la llar", "Salut", "Transport", "Comunicacions", 
"Oci i cultura", "Educació", "Restaurants i hotels", "Altres béns i serveis"
), class = "factor"), despesatotal = c(72550491701696000, 514691112000324, 
853338207044935, 26964294577958360, 1948071319668620, 816954427256048, 
3759365484618088, 566787384086023, 1978802503248884, 122472236797361, 
1603169228759177, 4471711267049114), despesamonetaria = c(71922177505370160, 
514060934967651, 852780110238510, 9150794396419362, 1946413539609788, 
816837090808086, 3753590662112487, 565752314409180, 1978515407744175, 
120444283968143, 0, 4440563217947374)), row.names = c(NA, -12L
), class = "data.frame"), tabyl_type = "two_way", totals = "row")
```

So the issue is that row number 11 `Resutarants i hotels`
& column number 3 `despesamonetaria` has a result of 0 but it's actually not 0.

I do not know where the error is coming from, as the other results are all correct.

Comment: Your `dput()` for `Despesa_2021_Red` doesn't seem to contain the variable `despesatotal` or `despesamonetaria`

Comment: Sorry, now it does.

Comment: You are either not working on the same df or you've selected the wrong df for your `dput()`. Your code does not produce the final dataframe. 

`despesatotal_llar` is a 6x6 dataframe and your final `dput()` of your result is 13x3.

Running your code shows `despesatotal_llar` having the `Restaurants i hotels` with the `desposamonetaria` having a value of 38.48054.

Comment: I just simplified a bit my code. My concern is that the other sums (for instance, `despesatotal_llar` having the `Transport`) are correct, except for `Restaurants i hotels`. And all of them come from the same df.

Comment: Ok, I just added `na.rm=TRUE`to my code and now it's working. I don't know why but R was giving `NAs` values to all the observations corresponding to `Restaurants i hotels`.